# How to enable Catalyst Query Optimiser in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, query-optimization, apache-spark-sql

Whether I use Spark-SQL directly or Spark-Shell, I have no idea to check the operation of Spark Catalyst Query Optimizer in explicit way.

For example, let we assume that I made HiveContext as follows:

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Then, when I try to process a query as:

```
hiveContext.sql("""
        | SELECT dt.d_year, item.i_brand_id brand_id, item.i_brand brand,SUM(ss_ext_sales_price) sum_agg
        | FROM  date_dim dt, store_sales, item
        | WHERE dt.d_date_sk = store_sales.ss_sold_date_sk
        |   AND store_sales.ss_item_sk = item.i_item_sk
        |   AND item.i_manufact_id = 128
        |   AND dt.d_moy=11
        | GROUP BY dt.d_year, item.i_brand, item.i_brand_id
        | ORDER BY dt.d_year, sum_agg desc, brand_id
        | LIMIT 100
        """).collect().foreach(println)
```

Is there way to check the existence of catalyst optimizer?
If not exists, then how can we enable catalyst optimizer for HiveContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Catalyst Query Optimizer** is always enabled in Spark 2.0. It is a part of the optimizations you get *for free* when you work with Spark 2.0's `Datasets` (and one of the many reasons you should really be using `Datasets` before going low level with `RDDs`).

If you want to see the optimizations Catalyst Query Optimizer applied to your query, use `TRACE` logging level for SparkOptimizer in `conf/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkOptimizer=TRACE
```

With that whenever you trigger execution of your query (through `show`, `collect` or a mere `explain`) you'll see tons of logs with the work Catalyst Query Optimizer is doing for you every time you execute a query.

Let's see [Column Pruning optimization rule](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L346) in action.

```
// the business object
case class Person(id: Long, name: String, city: String)

// the dataset to query over
val dataset = Seq(Person(0, "Jacek", "Warsaw")).toDS

// the query
// Note that we work with names only (out of 3 attributes in Person)
val query = dataset.groupBy(upper('name) as 'name).count

scala> query.explain(extended = true)
...
TRACE SparkOptimizer:
=== Applying Rule org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ColumnPruning ===
 Aggregate [upper(name#126)], [upper(name#126) AS name#160, count(1) AS count#166L]   Aggregate [upper(name#126)], [upper(name#126) AS name#160, count(1) AS count#166L]
!+- LocalRelation [id#125L, name#126, city#127]                                       +- Project [name#126]
!                                                                                        +- LocalRelation [id#125L, name#126, city#127]
...
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Aggregate [upper('name) AS name#160], [upper('name) AS name#160, count(1) AS count#166L]
+- LocalRelation [id#125L, name#126, city#127]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
name: string, count: bigint
Aggregate [upper(name#126)], [upper(name#126) AS name#160, count(1) AS count#166L]
+- LocalRelation [id#125L, name#126, city#127]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [upper(name#126)], [upper(name#126) AS name#160, count(1) AS count#166L]
+- LocalRelation [name#126]

== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[upper(name#126)#171], functions=[count(1)], output=[name#160, count#166L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(upper(name#126)#171, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[upper(name#126) AS upper(name#126)#171], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[upper(name#126)#171, count#173L])
      +- LocalTableScan [name#126]
```